# ID5100 is a Speaker Mic avail?

Tags: mobile, speaker

ID5100 mounted mobile in center console with only faceplate and mic exposed. Also have bluetooth headset. 
Besides the speakers built-in and external sp1 or sp2 does a handheld mic AND speaker like on the HT's exist?

Bluetooth thru car audio is cool for monitoring but not for transmit (feedback)

Working on a external speaker system now for both output jacks.

Answer (score 1):

Pin 3 on the modular mic connector, which is AF OUT on some Icom models (e.g. the IC-706) is labeled as "HM-207 detection, grounds when HM-207 is connected" on the ID-5100. So it appears that the 5100 doesn't have audio out on the mic jack, and any Icom-supplied mic with a speaker in it is incompatible. Any third-party speaker mic for this radio (I don't know if such a thing exists) would have to have both the modular mic connector *and* a 1/8" audio plug for the speaker audio.

As for feedback through the car speakers — do you have "TX monitor" set? If so, does turning it off improve things?

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. Humm not so useful in a mobile radio designed with remote head without a speaker like the 7100. I did fix the BT mic issues and also added a remote Kenwood KES-5 speaker and used a Y cable 2 male to one female 3.5mm headphone adapter and used it to hear both sides of radio sp1 & sp2 outputs with the one external speaker. Clear and loud!